# Stuck! DAX Measure(s) to group records by location and then by a date count

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm running into an issue when trying to return a bool value for "clustering" (customer term) of covid-items for their stores.

I'm using a sharepoint hosted list and the relevant columns are:

store_id;
date_of_infection;

Essentially, when I had planned to attempt is the following:

Group records by store_id, sort those grouped records by date_of_infection, return true if there are 10+ records on the same day at the same store (i.e. if there were 10+ infections at store_id 1 on 1/1/2021 this should return true. While 5 infections at store_id 2 and 5 infections at store_id 3 on 1/1/2021 would return false.)

> > If count_of_records >= 10 then True else False

Unfortunately we can't use SQL for this project and I'm now stuck in how to translate that intended result into DAX or PowerM.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Share some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

try a flag **Measure** as below-

```
flag = 
IF(
    count_of_records >= 10,
    1,
    0 
)
```